# Combine and minimize all .js files in parent folder

Tags: php, php5, cache

I'd appreciate some feedback on my latest PHP script. It is supposed to work like this:

1. When obtained, it checks whether the cache is still up-to-date
2. IF YES, return the cache; IF NOT, reset the cache
3. Get all JS scripts in the parent directory
4. Minimize the code
5. Add it to the cache
6. Return the cache

```
// Script combines & minimizes all .js files in the parent folder
// Result is cached until a change to the files is dealt

header('Content-type: application/x-javascript');

$cache_path = 'cache.txt';
$index_path = 'cache-index.txt';

function getScriptsInDirectory(){
    $array = Array();
    $scripts_in_directory = scandir('.');
    foreach ($scripts_in_directory as $script_name) {
        if (preg_match('/(.+)\.js/', $script_name))
        {
            array_push($array, $script_name);
        }
    }
    return $array;
}

function compilingRequired(){
    global $cache_path;
    global $index_path;
    if (file_exists($cache_path) && file_exists($index_path))
    {
        $cache_time = filemtime($cache_path);
        $files = getScriptsInDirectory();
        foreach ($files as $script_name) {
            if(filemtime($script_name) > $cache_time)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        $array = explode(PHP_EOL, file_get_contents($index_path));
        foreach($array as $name)
        {
            if (!file_exists($name))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

function compressScript($buffer) {
    $buffer = preg_replace('!/\*[^*]*\*+([^/][^*]*\*+)*/!', '', $buffer);
    $buffer = str_replace(array("\r\n","\r","\n","\t",'  ','    ','     '), '', $buffer);
    $buffer = preg_replace(array('(( )+{)','({( )+)'), '{', $buffer);
    $buffer = preg_replace(array('(( )+})','(}( )+)','(;( )*})'), '}', $buffer);
    $buffer = preg_replace(array('(;( )+)','(( )+;)'), ';', $buffer);
    return $buffer;
}

if (compilingRequired())
{
    if (file_exists($cache_path)){
        unlink($cache_path);    
        unlink($index_path);
    }

    $scripts_in_directory = getScriptsInDirectory();
    $file_handler = fopen($cache_path, 'w+');
    $cache_handler = fopen($index_path, 'w+');

    foreach ($scripts_in_directory as $name)
    {
        if (strlen(file_get_contents($cache_path)) > 0){
            fwrite($file_handler, str_repeat(PHP_EOL, 2));
        }

        fwrite($file_handler, '/**** ' . $name . ' ****/' . str_repeat(PHP_EOL, 2));
        fwrite($file_handler, compressScript(file_get_contents($name)));
        fwrite($cache_handler, $name . PHP_EOL);
    }

    echo file_get_contents($cache_path);
}
else
{
    echo file_get_contents($cache_path);
}
```

Comment: If you are able to use a more recent version of PHP, try refactoring this as OOP, and try functions like `glob` instead of `scandir`, they're cleaner.

Comment: @MMiller - or even SPL (Directory, DirectoryIterator, RecursiveDirectoryIterator) if they can refactor to OOP on a newer PHP version

Answer (score 1):

This snippet at the end...

```
if (compilingRequired())
{
    if (file_exists($cache_path)){
        unlink($cache_path);    
        unlink($index_path);
    }

    $scripts_in_directory = getScriptsInDirectory();
    $file_handler = fopen($cache_path, 'w+');
    $cache_handler = fopen($index_path, 'w+');

    foreach ($scripts_in_directory as $name)
    {
        if (strlen(file_get_contents($cache_path)) > 0){
            fwrite($file_handler, str_repeat(PHP_EOL, 2));
        }

        fwrite($file_handler, '/**** ' . $name . ' ****/' . str_repeat(PHP_EOL, 2));
        fwrite($file_handler, compressScript(file_get_contents($name)));
        fwrite($cache_handler, $name . PHP_EOL);
    }

    echo file_get_contents($cache_path);
}
else
{
    echo file_get_contents($cache_path);
}
```

If they both end the same, there's really no need for an else case, you can just put the statement after the if statement.

```
if (compilingRequired())
{
    if (file_exists($cache_path)){
        unlink($cache_path);    
        unlink($index_path);
    }

    $scripts_in_directory = getScriptsInDirectory();
    $file_handler = fopen($cache_path, 'w+');
    $cache_handler = fopen($index_path, 'w+');

    foreach ($scripts_in_directory as $name)
    {
        if (strlen(file_get_contents($cache_path)) > 0){
            fwrite($file_handler, str_repeat(PHP_EOL, 2));
        }

        fwrite($file_handler, '/**** ' . $name . ' ****/' . str_repeat(PHP_EOL, 2));
        fwrite($file_handler, compressScript(file_get_contents($name)));
        fwrite($cache_handler, $name . PHP_EOL);
    }
}
echo file_get_contents($cache_path);
```

Ideally, though, it'd read something like

```
if (compilingRequired())
{
    compile();
}
printCompressedFiles();
```

Because you want to program on the same level of abstraction - high level code is in "programmer english", describing the actions that need to be done (basically that list of 6 steps of yours, maybe compressed a bit). Low level code is pretty much regular code - code actually doing the work.